# Audio Matching in Android

Tags: android, audio

In server audio files are there having 2 minutes. I have to record some audio(in 5- 10 sec) on Android device and then send to server to match.

I have to match audio.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Acoustic Fingerprinting?](http://tinyurl.com/49vbyeq)

Or, see this article: [Efficient Index-Based Audio Matching](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/10376/4432632/04432645.pdf?arnumber=4432645)

Answer (score 1):

Alex Restrepo was able to get the open source Echoprint code running on Android.  Sounds like exactly what you are looking for. You can read more about it here:

https://aci.cis.gvsu.edu/2012/01/25/android-echoprint/

The code along with a sample Android application using it can be found here:

https://github.com/gvsumasl/EchoprintForAndroid